# How to add JWT token to authorization header?

Tags: php, header

I'm new in PHP world so I believe my question is easy one.

I am not sure if I understand how it works, but I think I should add JWT token to header "authorization". For now authorization is only as value in Access-Control-Allow-Headers, but if I've got it correctly, I should create Header with key authorization which would have JWT token as value.

I think I should use "header()" function after successful login but I am not sure how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was my problem with String operations in PHP. I was trying to create string like:

```
   header("Authorization: Bearer "+ $token);
```

but I've should do it like this:

```
   header("Authorization: Bearer " .$token);
```